# Intercept click on Notification bar Android 4 (tablet)

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is there any way to block click on notification bar in android 4 tablet. I knw there is no direct method but is there any bypass method ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**NO** you can't handle notification bar click event .

the only thing can be possible is that to handle click event of notification icon which is belong to your application. you cant event handle the click event of the other notification bar icon